# Query Laravel nested collection value using where condition

Tags: laravel

I have two collections of array in as follow:

One from `savings_account`s table and another one from `savings_products` table.

```json
{
  "id": 13,
  "account_number": "0012",
  "savings_product_id": 1,
  "balance": "500.00",
  "savings_product": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fixed",
    "interest_rate": "3.00"
  }
}
```

In Laravel Blade, I would like to query if "interest_rate" is greater than 0, which is in the 2nd collection.

I tried the code below, and it doesn't work.

```
{{ $data->where('interest_rate', '>', '0')->sum('balance') }}
```

Comment: How are you fetching `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation to make a condition on property from nested collection.

```
   $list = [
       ["id"=>13,"account_number"=>"0012", "savings_product_id"=> 1, "balance"=>"500.00", "savings_product"=>["id"=>1,"name"=>"Fixed", "interest_rate"=>"3.00"]],
       ["id"=>8,"account_number"=>"0082", "savings_product_id"=> 7, "balance"=>"120.00", "savings_product"=>["id"=>7,"name"=>"InProgress", "interest_rate"=>"4.0"]]
   ];

   $sum = collect($list)->where("savings_product.interest_rate")->sum("balance");
   dd($sum); 
  //620
```